# Set EXM layout directory location

Tags: exm

I have updated the location of "SampleNewsletter" directory location to allow seamless integration in my builds but it looks like in the message editor [image: message editor], only layout.cshtml is updated and the other razor files (header, footer, etc) are not being updated from the new folder. [image: File Structure]

The updated file path in: /sitecore/layout/Layouts/System/Email/Sample Newsletter/Newsletter Layout
[image]

I suspect I would only need to update a path for the other partials to be included into layout.cshtml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EXM newsletter renderings are controller renderings. You will need to update the code to point to your new partial view folder. If you do not have the source, your options are limited.

Controller

```
public ActionResult Header()
{
    return this.View(this._repository.GetFixedSectionViewModel(RenderingContext.Current.Rendering));
}
```

Specifying your view path

```
public ActionResult Header()
{
    return this.View("/Views/EmailNews/Header.cshtml", this._repository.GetFixedSectionViewModel(RenderingContext.Current.Rendering));
}
```

[image]

Comment: You custom controller is inheriting from Sitecore.EmailCampaign.SampleNewsletter.Controllers.NewsletterController ?

Comment: I decompiled the Sitecore code and made my own project.

Comment: I would recommend the same thing